# Загрузка файла при запуске программы

Tags: java, android

Нужно при открытии программы загрузить файл в папку на sd-карте, причем если файл с таким же именем, то заменить его. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как подобное реализовать?

реализовывать обновление не надо надо просто чтоб файл скачивался по определенной ссылке и перезаписывался на sd карте самого устройства Android Studio

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: А настоящий вопрос - как реализовать автообновление?

Comment: реализовывать обновление не надо надо просто чтоб файл скачивался по определенной ссылке и перезаписывался на sd карте самого устройства Android Studio

Comment: Заупускайте на старте программы что нибудь, что будет блокировать пользователя. Например это может быть актвити без кнопок и без реакции на onBackPressed, алерт диалог или что нибудь ещё (мне, например, больше нравится активити с логотипом программы и прогрессбаром внизу). В onCreate для этой активити запускаете AsyncTack, который качает вам файл в doInBackground, а в onPostExecute сохраняет на карту. Все это время в прогресс бар публикуем выполнение закачки. Как только все закончено запускаем стартовую активити.